# Adding a LeadBolt App Ad - how to add a Runnable

Tags: android, leadbolt

The doc says I should add something like this to my code:

```
// create a new layout 
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this); 
/* 
Add any elements to your view 
*/ 
// make the view visible 
this.setContentView(layout); 
final Activity act = this;  

// now add the banner or overlay to the app 

layout.post(new Runnable() {  //what about this line?
public void run() { 
myController = new AdController(act, MY_LB_SECTION_ID); 
myController.loadAd(); 
} 
});
```

My layout is in xml and I have already defined `setContentView(R.layout.config);` I mean the `layout.post(new Runnable() { line`. How should I modify the code?

Comment: Noone? I don't this has anything to do with LeadBolt, the question is how to set the runnable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is interested I have found the obvious solution:

```
  RelativeLayout rellaymain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rellaymain); 

        final Activity act = this;  
        rellaymain.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() { 
            myController = new AdController(act, MY_LB_SECTION_ID2); 
            myController.setAsynchTask(true);
            myController.loadAd(); 
            } 
            //});
        });
```

rellaymain is the layout of the .xml file.